# List of tuples into dictionary

Tags: python, tuples

I've got some issue with an understanding of how python converts a list of tuples into the dictionary. For instance,

```
from itertools import combinations as comb
a=[1,2,3,4]
l_t=list(comb(a,2))
print(l_t)
d_t=dict(l_t)
print(d_t)
```

and the output is:

```
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
{1: 4, 2: 4, 3: 4}
```

I'm just wondering what is happening during the conversion if we have several equal keys.
I don't understand why do I have only one value for the key "1", one for the key "2" and so on?
Sorry, probably the silly question, but I've found the answer yet
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How would you expect a dictionary to provide more than one value per key? What would you expect ``d_t[1]`` to evaluate to?

Answer (score 0):

As we can see the generated dict contains the last elements of each tuple[0]

[(1, 2), (1, 3), (**1**, 4), (2, 3), (**2**, 4), (**3**, 4)]

{1: 4, 2: 4, 3: 4}

it means that the code

```
dict(list_of_tuples)
```

works like:

```
d = {}
lst = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
for x in lst:
  d[x[0]] = x[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

In a dictionary the keys are unique, so there cannot be multiple keys using the same 'name'.
You could make use of [setDefault](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) and use an empty list to collect all values:

```
d = {}
l = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
for key, value in l:
    d.setdefault(key, [])
    d[key].append(value)

print(d)
```

Out:

```
{1: [2, 3, 4], 2: [3, 4], 3: [4]}
```

Comment: In the question, there is no for-loop which could overwrite previous values.

Comment: FWIW, `d.setdefault(key, []).append(value)` is how you typically use that…